# How can I use hypertools plot the dynamic graphic about mouse trajectory according to time?

Tags: python, plot

I find a powerful tool in kaggle which is [hypertools](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/04/10/exploring-the-structure-of-high-dimensional-data-with-hypertools-in-kaggle-kernels/). I find that it can plot dynamic graph. Just a single line code.

```
hyp.plot(temps, normalize='across', animate=True, chemtrails=True)
```

[image]

Sorry, the format `.gif` is more than 2MB. So I turn it into picture.However, you can watch this `gif` in [this](http://5047-presscdn.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/temps.gif). I think this is petty cool. However, I do not know how use this tools to plot for my data. My data is a list of tuple (x, y, t) like this:

```
array([[  353.,  2607.,   349.],
       [  367.,  2607.,   376.],
       [  388.,  2620.,   418.],
       [  416.,  2620.,   442.],
       [  500.,  2620.,   493.],
       [  584.,  2620.,   547.],
       [  675.,  2620.,   592.],
       [  724.,  2620.,   643.],
       [  780.,  2620.,   694.],
       [  822.,  2620.,   742.],
       [  850.,  2633.,   793.],
       [  885.,  2633.,   844.],
       [  934.,  2633.,   895.],
       [  983.,  2633.,   946.],
       [ 1060.,  2633.,  1006.],
       [ 1144.,  2633.,  1063.],
       [ 1235.,  2633.,  1093.],
       [ 1284.,  2633.,  1144.],
       [ 1312.,  2633.,  1210.],
       [ 1326.,  2633.,  1243.],
       [ 1333.,  2633.,  1354.],
       [ 1354.,  2633.,  1408.],
       [ 1375.,  2646.,  1450.],
       [ 1452.,  2659.,  1492.],
       [ 1473.,  2672.,  1543.],
       [ 1480.,  2672.,  1954.]])
```

How can I use this powerful tool to plot mouse trajectory?

Answer (score 1):

Hypertools only support animations for datasets with dimensionality>=3. Your mouse data is 3D but one of the axes is time, so visualizing that dimension as an animation is probably not that useful. You could try using the `animation` functions in `matplotlib`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.randn(200,2)
line, = ax.plot(data[0,0], data[0,1])


def animate(i):
    line.set_data(data[:i,:].T)  # update the data
    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_data(data[0,0], data[0,1])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), 
init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)
plt.xlim(min(data[:,0]), max(data[:,0]))
plt.ylim(min(data[:,1]), max(data[:,1]))
plt.show()
```